# How can I use powershell to list all files I uploaded to server?

Tags: networking, powershell, user, dir

At work there's a network and everyone has a username and password that they use to log in. How can I search for my files on this network?

I could list all the files like this:

```
cd \\192.168.*.***\f:\
dir -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

dir is the old way for DOS / Windows, Powershell gives you `get-childItem`

You should identify the directory you want to look for your files on, and then do something like:

```
$myDir = "\\Server\Directory\"

get-ChildItem -Path $myDor | Foreach {
 get-Acl $_
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
After editing the first line to the proper directory I just run it in powershell and it should work?

Comment: That is a start at least. Once you run that you will get the root objects and go from there. There is not recursion which you can easily add, and you would need to check the ACLs for your AD account as owner (hopefully).

Comment: "and you would need to check the ACLs for your AD account as owner (hopefully). –"
What do you mean? I'm not that techy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the files that are owned by you by using the following code

```
Get-ChildItem \\server\share -Recurse | Where-Object { 

    ($_ | Get-ACL).Owner -match $env:USERNAME 
}
```

The [Get-ACL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849802.aspx) cmdlet gets the ACL and ownership for the folder/file and compares it to  the [$env:USERNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-to-get-current-username-in-windows-powershell) variable which is the current username you are logged on to.